# How to adjust the input/output increments of a form

Tags: html

I am trying to create a form that will display a total based on multiple inputs.  Each input would be multiplied by a certain factor. Currently I have:

```html
<form method="post"
oninput="total.value= parseInt(a.value*1.5)+parseInt(b.value*2)+parseInt(c.value*1.5).toFixed(2)">

<input type="number" id="a" name="a" value="0" min="0" step="1.0">
<input type="number" id="b" name="b" value="0" min="0" step="1.0">
<input type="number" id="c" name="c" value="0" min="0" step="1.0">


<output name="total" for="a b c"></output>

</form>
```

When I run this, the first two inputs result in outputs in multiples of 10 or 15. Selecting "1" in the first input should output "1.5" but instead outputs "10", and selecting "2" outputs "30" instead of "3".  Selecting "1" in the last input at least outputs "1" instead of "10", but it should be "1.5".

How do I fix this so that the outputs are not multiplied and so that the result is accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to convert the values to numbers first, like so ( +a.value is the same as Number(a.value) ):

```html
<form method="post"
oninput="total.value= ((+a.value*1.5)+(+b.value*2)+(+c.value*1.5)).toFixed(2)">

<input type="number" id="a" name="a" value="0" min="0" step="1.0">
<input type="number" id="b" name="b" value="0" min="0" step="1.0">
<input type="number" id="c" name="c" value="0" min="0" step="1.0">


<output name="total" for="a b c"></output>

</form>
```